# Get type of last function from arbitrary amount of closures

Tags: typescript

Consider a function:

```
const f = a => b => ... x => { return somevalue }
```

How do I get the type for just the last function `typeof x => { return somevalue }` without knowing the total amount of closures?

My initial thought is that we need to build a type that uses recursion and conditional type checking until we reach the end. However, I'm not sure if typescript supports recursive types for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Recursive conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002) will be supported in TypeScript 4.1 when it comes out.  For now it's available in `typescript@next`.  Then you'll be able to write something like

```
type LastFunc<T extends (...args: any) => any> =
    T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? 
    R extends (...args: any) => any ? LastFunc<R> : T : never;
```

and use it on your `f` function:

```
declare const somevalue: SomeValue;
const f = (a: any) => (b: any) => (c: any) => (d: any) => (x: any) => { return somevalue }
type LastFuncF = LastFunc<typeof f>; // type LastFuncF = (x: any) => SomeValue
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=next#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgZ2AMQK4DsDGAeAKlCAD2AnQBMEoAKAOjrgCcBzBALijnRAEooBeAHwcuQvgCgokqPiIlylWvWZthPfkICW6AGYQGUAEpQA-IYLFSFanRqMW7TmsGqTsRCgw4DQ9vnboIADc9AG4xMS0SBm04TGgAZQB7AFsIADU4ABtUaABvDnYkBi0mKABfcLIITEzGaExE9CQoBBSgrJz2JNSM7IgwhqbgKG1+ajgHLl5nKgAjSachKkwF6aWyVfVqQk3nfIYIYFQGdBa2wI7oCtBINyQ0LGQx+HvPbBuIRNHtARCoAHp-lAPncPI8xlQdqo1lBuulLkA)

---

Until then, you can use either an unsupported workaround to get this behavior, like the following deferred-object-lookup thing which is confusing and annoying:

```
type LastFunc<T extends (...args: any) => any> =
    T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? {
        0: LastFunc<Extract<R, (...args: any) => any>>, 1: T
    }[R extends (...args: any) => any ? 0 : 1] : never
```

or you can use only supported features by unrolling the loop to a fixed depth, which is redundant and annoying:

```
type LastFunc<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R extends (...args: any) => any ? LF0<R> : T : never;
type LF0<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R extends (...args: any) => any ? LF1<R> : T : never;
type LF1<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R extends (...args: any) => any ? LF2<R> : T : never;
type LF2<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R extends (...args: any) => any ? LF3<R> : T : never;
type LF3<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R extends (...args: any) => any ? LF4<R> : T : never;
type LF4<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R extends (...args: any) => any ? LF5<R> : T : never;
type LF5<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R extends (...args: any) => any ? LF6<R> : T : never;
type LF6<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R extends (...args: any) => any ? LF7<R> : T : never;
type LF7<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R extends (...args: any) => any ? LF8<R> : T : never;
type LF8<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R extends (...args: any) => any ? LF9<R> : T : never;
type LF9<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R extends (...args: any) => any ? LFX<R> : T : never;
type LFX<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R extends (...args: any) => any ? R : T : never;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBVYUCuMYHsBOALhACZIDeAUBUjUgQJ4zIAyIUBAYhsPADwAqSCAA8iwYlCQAKAHRyQeAOZQAXEhDB6ASiQBeAHzrNh3dVrnBIsROlyZC5Wo3a9hgJbAAZhDxIASkgA-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-7tjQnYcNhoEwSeS6ZlBPbHjeS5TohT7UWOtHIhhIYAKw4X+MYEQKQEcJxpE0YurFDuKQnMSJRb3tOSHQcJEErgAbFxW48YBLAcCpEnXlJZ4XshYGwbeSD0Y+5ZHpJikfgA7KpeHqfG-F2TpqFwda4mGWRLHSQh5leQpaHLh+AAc9mtgBTmaWFrngUFlGefJVlBWZM5Jbp1mJgAnOF+Eadl3ajhl8Vib+6VuSZqVyUxxXuWxHAABq5Y5HZ7o1hWWbVJkJWVNUVXRMkMRZKFxXV76lpuDk7mcNAzD48yIEg0qyts5B7E8BCHMAxynFUFxXDcSAAuwxKQKScofC8K2-P89wncC4pSGCQUwlaUiIi9qIvZiQU4niBJEs8Z1kqcUX6rEdJiuDIosoK7JAlyvL8p2BqQyCUg-e5y3fBQ1RAA)

---

Personally I'd just wait until TS4.1, if I were you.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!